# Copy dependencies AND plugins with Maven

Tags: maven, dependencies

As our customer wants to build the project at his environment we have to deliver (beside the sources) our dependencies and our used plugins both not available from MavenCentral.

How can I copy the used plugins (including their dependencies but without referring each) in a way like the dependencies plugin is doing it for "normal" libs?

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-acme-dependencies</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <addParentPoms>true</addParentPoms>
                <copyPom>true</copyPom>
                <useRepositoryLayout>true</useRepositoryLayout>
                <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
                <includeGroupIds>org.acme</includeGroupIds>
                <excludeGroupIds>${project.groupId}</excludeGroupIds>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependencies</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Do your client has internal artifactory like [jFrog](https://jfrog.com/)? If yes, then you can deploy those there for further use.

Comment: I have to package our dependencies and deliver them to a customer. They will import them into their repository.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way would be to build your project against an empty Maven local repository and copy/enumerate the artifacts that find there afterwards.

Unfortunately, I never found a Maven plugin that lists you "everything you need to build a given project".